# How to set a different values to an input fields after selecting a combination of radio buttons using AND and OR selection in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, radio-button

So the problem is this: I have 6 pairs of radio buttons each represents a **“yes/no”** statement.

I have also `4 read-only` input fields to which I need to assign a value `(1 or 0)` after the user selects a combination of `radio` buttons.

The problem is that there are rules for value assignment:

1. if `(question 1)` OR `(question 2)` are `“yes”` -> `combi(1) =1, combi(2, 3, 4)=0` (that was easy. My code works)
2. If `(question 3)` OR `(question 4)` OR `(question 5)` are `“yes”` -> `combi(2) =1, combi(1,2,4)=0` (that was easy. My code works)
3. If `(question 1) AND [(question 2) OR (question 3) OR (question 4)]` are `“yes”` -> `combi(3)=1, combi(1,2,4)=0` **(here is the problem No 1)**
4. If `(question 1) AND [(question 2) OR (question 3) OR (question 4)] AND (question 5)` are `“yes”` -> `combi(4)=1, combi(1,2,3)=0` **(here is the problem No 2)**
5. If `(question 1,2,3,4,5)` are `NO` -> `combi(1,2,3,4)=0`. **(that was easy. My code works)**.

The problem short - I need to make a `AND` and `OR` selection in `JQuery` based on the selected buttons.
So here is my code. I think the third and fourth `“else if”` are with wrong selection

```
Question 1
<input id="q1a" type="radio" name="q1"> yes
<input id="q1b" type="radio" name="q1"> no
<br/>
Question 2
<input id="q2a" type="radio" name="q2"> yes
<input id="q2b" type="radio" name="q2"> no
<br/>
Question 3
<input id="q3a" type="radio" name="q3"> yes
<input id="q3b" type="radio" name="q3"> no
<br/>
Question 4 
<input id="q4a" type="radio" name="q4"> yes
<input id="q4b" type="radio" name="q4"> no
<br/>
Question 5
<input id="q5a" type="radio" name="q5"> yes
<input id="q5b" type="radio" name="q5"> no
<br/>
Question 6
<input id="q6a" type="radio" name="q6"> yes
<input id="q6b" type="radio" name="q6"> no
<br/>

<input id="combi1" type="text" readonly="true">Combi1<br/>
<input id="combi2" type="text" readonly="true">Combi1<br/>
<input id="combi3" type="text" readonly="true">Combi1<br/>
<input id="combi4" type="text" readonly="true">Combi1<br/>

JQuery 
$('input').click(function(e){
if ($('#q1a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q2a').is(':checked')){
$('#combi1').val(1) &&
$('#combi2').val(0) &&
$('#combi3').val(0) &&
$('#combi4').val(0);
}
else if ($('#q3a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q4a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q5a').is(':checked')){
$('#combi1').val(0) &&
$('#combi2').val(1) &&
$('#combi3').val(0) &&
$('#combi4').val(0);
}
else if ($('#q1a').is(':checked') &&
$('#q3a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q4a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q5a').is(':checked')){
$('#combi1').val(0) &&
$('#combi2').val(0) &&
$('#combi3').val(1) &&
$('#combi4').val(0);
}
else if ($('#q1a').is(':checked') &&
$('#q3a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q4a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q5a').is(':checked') &&
$('#q6a').is(':checked')) {
$('#combi1').val(0) &&
$('#combi2').val(0) &&
$('#combi3').val(0) &&
$('#combi4').val(1);
}
else if ($('#q1b').is(':checked') &&
$('#q2b').is(':checked') &&
$('#q3b').is(':checked') &&
$('#q4b').is(':checked') &&
$('#q5b').is(':checked')){
$('#combi1').val(0) &&
$('#combi2').val(0) &&
$('#combi3').val(0) &&
$('#combi4').val(0);
}
})
```

Comment: `&&` and `||` should only be used inside of `if(...)` or `else(...)`, they shouldn't appear between your `.val(0)` operations - rather, each of those lines should just end in a semi-colon (or not, doesn't really matter here). As for your issues with the more complex conditions not working properly, I'd take a second look at what your statements are actually saying, you're going to need a few extra sets of parenthesis to group your AND and OR statements properly. (as a hint, look at where the `[` and `]` symbols fall in your description)

Comment: The first, second and fifth “if” worked properly if I remove the third and the fourth. I fail to make a selection with && and || in the same “If”...

Comment: @jmcgriz Thanks for the advice!!! I solve it! First I did revised the logic bearing in mind that || stops at first TRUE statement and && stops at the first FALSE statement -  meaning I put the most complex combination as first in the if/else sequence and the most simple as last. Then I followed your advice and I did add an extra parentheses to combine the && and || properly. And now it works perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it!
Here it is how: First I did revised the logic bearing in mind that **|| stops at first TRUE statement** and **&& stops at the first FALSE statement** -  meaning I put the most complex combination as first in the if/else sequence and the most simple as last. Then I followed the advice of **jmcgriz** and I did add an extra parentheses to combine the && and || properly. And now it works!

Here is the working code.
If someone have a better or shorter version I am opened for it!!!

```
$('input').click(function(e){
if ($('#q1a').is(':checked') &&
$('#q6a').is(':checked') &&
($('#q3a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q4a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q5a').is(':checked'))) {
$('#combi1').val(0) &&
$('#combi2').val(0) &&
$('#combi3').val(0) &&
$('#combi4').val(1);
}
else if (($('#q1a').is(':checked')) &&
($('#q3a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q4a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q5a').is(':checked'))){
$('#combi1').val(0) &&
$('#combi2').val(0) &&
$('#combi3').val(1) &&
$('#combi4').val(0);
}
else if ($('#q3a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q4a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q5a').is(':checked')){
$('#combi1').val(0) &&
$('#combi2').val(1) &&
$('#combi3').val(0) &&
$('#combi4').val(0);
}
else if ($('#q1a').is(':checked') ||
$('#q2a').is(':checked')){
$('#combi1').val(1) &&
$('#combi2').val(0) &&
$('#combi3').val(0) &&
$('#combi4').val(0);
}
else {
$('#combi1').val(0) &&
$('#combi2').val(0) &&
$('#combi3').val(0) &&
$('#combi4').val(0);
}
})
```